# Perl re negative look behind Variable length error

Tags: regex, perl

This regular expression works fine for matching the pattern 'ab_' when not preceded by a single quote or a dollar sign:

```
/(?<!('|\$))ab_/
```

but if I try, for example, to add a bracket before the single quote

```
/(?<!(\['|\$))ab_/
```

I get this error

```
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex;
```

What does this error mean and is there a way to make the second example work?
It is likely I am overlooking something basic since I am no expert, so please point out anything I am missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error means that in Perl, a lookbehind assertion has to have a fixed-length pattern. `('|\$)` is fine because the pattern only matches a length-1 substring, but `(\['|\$)` could match either a length-1 substring (`$`) or a length-2 substring (`['`).

In your case, you can fix this by just using two separate lookbehinds, each with a fixed-length pattern, one for each case you want to rule out:

```
/(?<!\[')(?<!\$)ab_/
```